# Spring data - repository usage performance

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data

We are developing a web application using spring framework and MySQL database.

Is there a major performance difference between the 2 update flows:

1) using the following PlayerRepository function:

```
@Query("UPDATE Player p SET p.firstName = ?2, p.lastName = ?3, p.age = ?4 WHERE p.id = ?1")
@Modifying
public int setSomeFields(Long playerId, String firstName, String lastName, Long age);
```

In the PlayerService:

```
@Transactional
public void setSomeFields(Long playerId, String firstName, String lastName, Long age) {
       this.playerRepository.setSomeFields(playerId, firstName, lastName, age);

}
```

2) using the following method in PlayerService:

```
@Transactional
public void setSomeFields(Long playerId, String firstName, String lastName, Long age) {
       this.playerRepository.setFirstName(firstName, playerId);
       this.playerRepository.setLastName(lastName, playerId);
       this.playerRepository.setAge(age, playerId);

}
```

Are the more or less equivalent in performance? The 2nd method is more flexible for me when i would like to support partial updates and I want to make sure this way is viable before implementing.

Comment: Neither... Why aren't you just updating a `Player` object and let hibernate figure out what is the most efficient way. Option 2 generates more queries so in theory is slower. But imho your whole approach is wrong.

Comment: If I'm fetching objects with hibernate than I fetch alot of unnecessary data with it, If i want to update a specific field why should i fetch from DB the whole object? Why not executing an update query and be done with it? More over - If i'll fetch I will have to use locking mechanism.

Comment: You will have to use a locking mechanism either way regardless of the fact if you use hibernate or not (IMHO). You also might want to read up on how JPA/Hibernate works if you retrieve a single player you can also get a proxy for that player instead of the real object and do objects on that). Next to that it looks to me if you are trying to prematurely optimize for something that might not even be a problem, not to mention the additional burden you create for updates. Imagina 120 fields you can update, how aer you going to manage that? It might look like a good idea now, but is it really?